# HDD not installed after Ubuntu install Ideapad 15ALC05

Tags: 20.04, ssd, lenovo, amd-ryzen

I got an brand new 15ALC05 (ryzen 7) and tried to setup ubuntu(20.04.2.0 LTS) 
dual boot using a bootable usb drive. After successful installation when I tried to restart I get the boot menu with Windows boot manager, Ubuntu and Setup. The only option that works is "Setup" that takes me to Bios setup.
 
Also in the Information tab in the Bios setup I see "HDD : Not installed".
 
I called up Lenovo support and they sent a support tech to replace the SSD(NVMe gen 3).
Post this I decided to just have ubuntu (no windows) on the laptop was able to install Ubuntu successfully and restart a few times. After a couple of restarts I see the same issue with the "HDD: Not installed".
 
The Laptop now does not have Windows 10 however the Boot menu with Windows Boot manager, Ubuntu and Setup still shows up. And I am no longer able to boot into Ubuntu.
 
The only other thing that I can think of the second time was that I was trying to connect my external monitor via HDMI after when this happened, but not sure if it is related.
 
Questions

1. Why does this happen? Is the SSD actually dead or is it somehow not accessible?
2. How do I get the Bios to recognize the SSD now?
3. I can replace the SSD myself, but how do I ensure that this does not happen when I re-install Ubuntu?
    
   Please help.
   [image: BIOS Configuration Screen]
   [image: BIOS Information]

Comment: Hi. Can you post configuration screen. Is the hard drive configured as intel rst mode?

Comment: @jpbrain Posted the config screen. I don't see a hard drive config there.

Comment: Hi.. do you have any way to test the disk on another computer? through an external case or something like that. I had some similar issues with my daughter's Lenovo but it was an intel rst configuration problem. after disabling it everything worked fine. Not sure if it is the same situation. Could be that your drive it is failing too.

Comment: @jpbrain I’ve ordered a case to connect the disk to another computer. This is the second disk that has failed with a similar installation, so will be surprised if this is a hardware failure. I’ve cross posted this on the Lenovo forum and there’s a response there about trying to format as EFI. There may be an issue with how I have created the usb install drive for Ubuntu as well. Im not sure I chose the right UEFI settings in rufus. So I’m going to try that. But I want to check if I can save the disk first.

Comment: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-IdeaPad-1xx-3xx-5xx-7xx-Edge-LaVie-Z-Flex-Notebooks/HDD-not-installed-after-Ubuntu-install-Ideapad-15ALC05/m-p/5092106?page=1#5395666

Comment: nope. if it where an EFI/UEFI problem... you could not be able to boot but bios should show the drive. Once the bios show the drive we move to the next step.

Comment: @jpbrain thanks. Will update once I can test the drive on another computer. Could be a while to get the adapter.

Comment: Alos, try to disable secure boot on bios to see if situation change.

Comment: Yup. Done that already. No difference.